# Mapping an ADT to multiple columns in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to map an ADT (`case class`es inheriting from a `sealed trait`) as multiple columns of the same table, using Slick, something like:

```
sealed trait OrValue
case class IntValue(value: Int)
case class StringValue(value: String)

case class Thing(id: Int, value: OrValue)

class Things(tag: Tag) extends Table[Thing](tag, "things") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def intValue = column[Option[Int]]("intValue")
  def stringValue = column[Option[String]]("stringValue")

  def toThing(_id: String, _intValue: Option[Int], _stringValue: Option[String]): Thing = Thing(id, ((_intValue, _stringValue) match {
    case (Some(a), None) => IntValue(a)
    case (None, Some(a)) => StringValue(a)
  }

  def fromThing(t: Thing): (String, Option[Int], Option[String]) = ??? // elided

  def * = (id, intValue, stringValue) <> ((toThing _).tupled, fromThing)
}
```

This is not compling:

```
[error]  found   : [U]slick.lifted.MappedProjection[Thing,U]
[error]  required: slick.lifted.ProvenShape[Thing]
[error]            ) <> ((toThing _).tupled, fromThing _)
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way?
What's the idiomatic way of representing an ADT?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in signature of methods `toThing` and `fromThing`.

It should look so:

```
sealed trait OrValue
case class IntValue(value: Int)
case class StringValue(value: String)

case class Thing(id: Int, value: OrValue)

class Things(tag: Tag) extends Table[Thing](tag, "things") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def intValue = column[Option[Int]]("intValue")
  def stringValue = column[Option[String]]("stringValue")

  def toThing(source: (Int, Option[Int], Option[String])): Thing = source match {
    case (id, intValue, stringValue) => ??? //TODO implement
  }
  def fromThing(t: Thing): Option[(Int, Option[Int], Option[String])] = ??? //TODO implement

  def * = (id, intValue, stringValue) <> (toThing _, fromThing _)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't name mapping and case classes with the same name. Change map class to `Things`, for example.